# Applying SVG effects to HTML content

Tags: html, css, svg, xhtml

I am trying to follow this tutorial to add an SVG mask to my HTML div element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content

Here's the relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <svg height="0">
        <mask id="mask_1">
            <linearGradient id="grad_1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
                <stop offset="0.0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.0" />
                <stop offset="1.0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1.0" />
            </linearGradient>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="72" height="72" fill="url(#grad_1)"/>
        </mask>
    </svg>
    <div style="left:0px;top:0px;width:68px;height:68px;background-color:#ff0000;background-size:auto;mask:url(#mask_1);">Here's some text.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The mask is not working however. The div elements are being rendered properly, minus the mask that is supposed to make them fade toward the top. Am I missing something obvious? Does this method only work in XHTML versus HTML 5? Thanks.

Comment: which browser are you using?  That seems to have an effect in Firefox/Mac for me but not in others.

Comment: I was using Chrome. But I just tried it in Firefox and it worked, so I guess the browser is the problem. I guess I will have to scrap my plans in that case. :(

Comment: Maybe I am not using the right doctype? I tried using XHTML and got the same failing results in Chrome.

Comment: I think you'd have to use a CSS mask/gradient for it to work in Chrome. I don't think that UA supports SVG gradients/masks on html.